# Simpler way to get duplicates from a list in groovy

Tags: groovy

Given the list:

```
list: [
   object1: {
     id: 22,
     name: "Tom"
   },
   object2: {
     id: 12,
     name: "Mary"
   },
   object3: {
     id: 44,
     name: "Tom"
   }
]
```

Instead of using nested loops, is there any other one-liner that would get ONLY duplicated names from this list ? So the return list would be `["Tom"]`

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to group them with a count, and find all the ones where the count is greater than one:

```
list.name.countBy { it }.findResults { it.value > 1 ? it.key : null }
```

Or indeed as @Daniel says:

```
list.values().name.countBy { it }.findResults { it.value > 1 ? it.key : null }
```

Depending on your structure...

Comment: Need to access the internal maps: list*.value*.name.countBy { it }.findResults { it.value > 1 ? it.key : null }

Comment: @Daniel Not if the list variable is like in Jacob's answer

Comment: True, I was looking at the example in the question, but that isn't syntactically valid so I just assumed it was all a list of maps of maps...maybe they are objects that contain a "name" property.  That would make more sense!

Comment: This will return a list with the duplicated values. Is there anyway of returning those but with all the keys from the previous list?

Comment: This feels like another question  But if you store the duplicate names into a variable, ie: `def duplicates = list.values().name.countBy { it }.findResults { it.value > 1 ? it.key : null }`, you could then do `list.findAll { it.value.name in duplicates }` to return just the toms from the original map

Answer (score 1):

Close to a oneliner is the below code. The idea is to create a list of unique named elements, and remove them from the original list.

```
def list = [
    [ id: 22, name: "Tom"],
    [ id: 12, name: "Mary"],
    [ id: 44, name: "Tom"]
]

def unique = list.toUnique { a, b -> a.name <=> b.name }
list.removeAll(unique)
list*.name
```

removeAll returns booleon, so that complicates it if you need 1 line of code, the unique variable can be foldet into the method call.

Notice,  .toUnique() returns a new collection .unique() removes from the collection called on.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I hadn't seen `toUnique()` before and couldn't figure out why `unique()` kept modifying the original list when it returns a List; seems like it should be a `void` method if it modifies the original... Regardless, this was the answer I was looking for!